# Print preview screen is not showing the contents of my reactjs App

Tags: reactjs

I opened my React Application in Chrome and all the content has loaded.
But when i click Print(Ctrl +P ), the preview window is not loading any content.

Can someone please advise what can be the issue  or where I can start debugging ?
For example : My Component renders a h1 tag inside the form tag

`render() {`
`<form>`
`<h1>I love Stack Overflow</h1>`
`</form>`

Now, when i click on Print (Ctrl + P), the preview screen is blank.

But if i remove form tag and i only render h1 tag i,e
`render() {`
`<h1>I love Stack Overflow</h1>`

I can able to see the content in preview Screen.
So, the question is why, with form tag the preview Screen is coming blank.

Comment: What exactly you want to print?

Comment: Hi, Suppose my component has following code in the render <form><h1>hello there</h1></form>, then i want in the print preview Screen(Ctrl + P), "hello there" text to appear. But currently it is not appearing.
After bit of analysis i found if i remove <form> tag from my render and just give <h1>hello there</h1>, then the "hello there" text appears in Print Preview Screen.
I am not sure what exactly is the issue when i include form tag

Comment: please add the code to the question, code in the comment section won't help future readers

Comment: @ram10 Were you able to solve this issue?